# How do you increase a number *directly* under the cursor?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

In vim et al, you can increase or decrease the number your cursor is on by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>. However, this increases the whole number but I would like to simply increase the number directly under the cursor. It's a little hard to describe so here's what I mean:

```
Ctrl+A usage, cursor is over the "6":
[6]5 -> 66

What I need:
[6]5 -> 75

or:
3[8]90 -> 3990
```

I hope that makes sense.

I've googled a bit but I'm not sure if such a shortcut exists so any tips are much appreciated!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In this case, I usually type <kbd>r</kbd> and then the digit I want.

Comment: apt and simplest soln for the problem at hand. +1!

Comment: You can do it with one key (after setting this up ;-)), see my answer.

Answer (score 52):

`<C-a>` and `<C-x>` work on whole numbers (1 or more digits) but not on "parts" of a number. However it takes a "count" so `10<C-a>` turns `[6]5` into `75`.

Another option, since you only want to change one digit, would be to do `r7` to turn `[6]5` into `75`.

Comment: Sweet... now I can go down a list of single digits and "." increasing each one along the way.

Comment: An even better solution would be to provide exactly what the question asks, in a shortcut: a command to apply to a single digit: that is, to apply the increment to a single digit. I would suggest a keymapping (I don't know how to do it, but here is an idea) that would use `ctrl` + `X`/`A` + `another key` (such as `shift` perhaps since it is nearby key easy to press) => changing only current digit. Does this help, as an idea? Good question!!

Answer (score 8):

As I guess 3[9]42 shall become 4042 (otherwise, [Xavier's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10534509/15934) is almost perfect (*)), I'd use the following:

```
s/\d*\%#\d/\=(submatch(0)+1)
```

Which could be mapped into:

```
nnoremap <silent> µ :<c-u>s/\d*\%#\d/\=(submatch(0)+v:count1)<cr>``
```

in order to accept a count. The only catch I see is that it cannot support repeat (as in `:h .`)

(*) In the sense that repeating the command won't help us to increment a series of different numbers by the same amount.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I'd rather mark Xavier's solution as the accepted answer because it answered my question exactly but this is a better solution for my specific problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

There's probably a better way, but you can make a macro or something that maps to this:

```
noremap <LEADER>a a <ESC>h<C-a>lxh
noremap <LEADER>z a <ESC>h<C-z>lxh
```

It basically makes the "65" "6 5", increments the 6 and removes the space. There is probably a shorter version of this that would work too.

Answer (score 4):

In global command use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> to insert literal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> that means in normal mode increase every number `\d\+` by 10

```
:g/\d\+/norm! 10 Ctrl-v Ctrl-a
```

We can also avoid typing "Ctrl-v Ctrl-a", just use "exec" with double quotes as you see in the line below. If you try using single quotes this solution does not work.

```
:g/\d\+/exec "norm! 10\<C-a>"
```

In normal mode you can simply do:

```
10 Ctrl-a
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do `v11<C-A>x` it does `(digit + 11) modulo 10`
If you do this very often then you can map it to whatever you want (`<leader>a` ?).

note: if the digit is not a 9 then `v<C-A>` works.
I got this tip from [vimgolf](http://www.vimgolf.com/challenges/5c645526fa8ae200061757ad), I recommend this site :D

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like (use whatever intead of <kbd>F9</kbd>):

```
:nnoremap <F9> :exec 's@^\(.\{' . (col(".")-1) . '\}\)\(.\)\(.*\)@\1' . (getline(".")[col(".")-1]+1) . '\3@'<CR>
```

Basically it just finds the cursors position in the rows, builds a regex string upon it and uses the character on that position to add 1.

Comment: Can any one please explain this line ":nnoremap <F9> :exec 's@^\(.\{' . (col(".")-1) . '\}\)\(.\)\(.*\)@\1' . (getline(".")[col(".")-1]+1) . '\3@'<CR>".

Comment: Because I executed this line in vim, it was worked perfectly(It increment the number based on the cursor). But I can't understand what exactly this line did.

Answer (score 1):

`v <C-A/X>` works well since `<C-A/X>` works on either the word the cursor is on (that is a number) or the visual selection (that is a number).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind messing up the `"` register, here's another sequence that does it:

```
s<C-R>=<C-R>"+1<CR>
```

Comment: Pretty funky. I had no idea there would be so many different solutions ;) Thanks!